# Manipulating controls independently when they are added programmatically to an empty array - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I have an empty that is filled with the user's input. These items after they get added (type and press enter) also get a list of options (yes and no) using radio buttons. I need to be able to choose yes or no independently. As of now, because they all share the same v-model, they all change when I modify any of them. How can I single this out?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-pa-lg">
    <q-input
      outlined
      label="Enter App Number"
      style="margin-bottom:20px"
      color="primary"
      square
      dense
      type="text"
      v-model="applicationbarcode"
      @change="addApplication">       
    </q-input>
    <div class="group" v-for="(appItem, index) in appList" :key="index">
      <span>Application #: {{appItem}}</span>
      <q-option-group
        v-model="issuegroup"
        :options="issueoptions"
        color="primary"
        inline
      ></q-option-group>
    </div>        
  </div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  provide() {
    const menu = {};
    Object.defineProperty(menu, "appList", {
      enumerable: true,
      get: () => this.appList
    });
    return { menu };
  },
  data () {
    return {
      appList: [],      
      applicationbarcode: "",
      issuegroup: null,
      issueoptions: [
        {
          label: 'Yes',
          value: 'op1'
        },
        {
          label: 'No',
          value: 'op2'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    appAdded() {
      return this.appList[this.applicationbarcode].index;
    }
  },    
  methods: {
    addApplication: function(index) {
      this.appList.push(this.applicationbarcode);
      this.applicationbarcode = ""; 
    }  
  }
})
```

Here's a [**PLAYGROUND**](https://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/mddzKXx?editors=1010) for ya as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the individual items' data. Simplest way (IMHO) is to convert `appList` into an array of objects (instead of strings)

```js
    addApplication: function(index) {
      this.appList.push({barcode: this.applicationbarcode, issuegroup: null});
      this.applicationbarcode = "";

    }
```

And update the template to use the object array

```html
      <div class="group" v-for="(appItem, index) in appList" :key="index">
          <span>Application #: {{appItem.barcode}}</span>
          <q-option-group
            v-model="appItem.issuegroup"
            :options="issueoptions"
            color="primary"
            inline
          ></q-option-group>
      </div>
```

Alternatively, you could set up another array for the values, but then you may need to worry about matching keys/indices, if you want to start removing items.

Comment: BOOM! Exactly what I was looking for! Why didn't I think about passing the issuegroup value to the push? duh! I need a break lol. Thanks brother

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert `issuegroup` to the dictionary.

```
  issuegroup: {},
```

And update the template to use `appItem` as key.

```
  <q-option-group
        v-model="issuegroup[appItem]"
        :options="issueoptions"
        color="primary"
        inline
      ></q-option-group>
```